# Could not find method classpath()

Tags: android, google-play-services, ionic2

I am a new in Ionic 2/Firebase and Android.

From Firebase Console I got the config variable and added it into my app.module.ts. Everything works fine on the web.

I followed the instructions to run my app on android but as Ionic2 has a different file structure I don't know where should I add this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`' and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

I am receiving this error

> Could not find method classpath()

when I tried to add them to the following path:

> "C:\myapp\platforms\android\build.gradle"  classpath
>   'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
>
> "C:\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle"  apply plugin:
>   'com.google.gms.google-services'

Anyone could help me out to config my app so that it would run on android and iOS?

Comment: Those go into a single Gradle file. Do you have one? If so, please show all of it

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Apply this in build.gradle(Project: your project name) where tools.build:gradle is present and not in build.gradle(Module: app)

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        }
    }
```

In build.gradle(Module: app) outside dependencies add this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.